# Disabling Timer .. why I can't?

Tags: c#, .net

When I use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` class and finish using it then I can't disable it.. it ticks even if I set its property `Enabled` to `false`. What is wrong with the code? here is an example:

```
int counter = 0;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    MessageBox.Show("Hello"); 
    counter++; 
    if (counter == 10){
       timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in all this is `counter` declared, and how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a subtle bug that's induced by the MessageBox.Show() call.  MessageBox pumps a message loop to keep the UI alive.  Which allows the Tick event handler to run again, even though it is already active from the previous tick.  The counter variable doesn't get incremented until you click the OK button.  As a result, the screen fills with message boxes and that won't stop until you click the OK button ten times.

You need to increment the counter *before* showing the message box.  Fix:

```
int counter = 0;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    counter++; 
    if (counter > 10) timer1.Enabled = false;
    else MessageBox.Show("Hello"); 
}
```

This kind of problem is also the reason that DoEvents() got such a bad reputation.  It is pretty difficult to write code that can properly deal with the re-entrancy induced by the message loop.  You need to keep boolean flags around that indicate that code is already active.  Which is another way to solve your problem:

```
int counter = 0;
bool showingBox = false;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    if (showingBox) return;
    showingBox = true;
    try {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello"); 
        counter++;
        if (counter == 10) timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
    finally {
        showingBox = false;
    }
}
```

You now get only one message box at a time, probably what you are really looking for.

I should mention that this re-entrancy problem is pretty specific to timers.  A dialog takes counter-measures to avoid re-entrancy problems, it disables all the windows in the application.  That ensures that the user cannot do things like closing the main window or clicking a button that brings up the dialog again.  Both rather disastrous mishaps.  That takes care of most of the 'unexpected' Windows notifications, basically any of the messages that are generated by the user.  The edge case is a timer (WM_TIMER is not disabled) whose event handler has a UI effect.

Comment: Thank you so verry much! Been handling this problem the whole day!

Answer (score 2):

It is because the `MessageBox.Show` blocks until the user presses OK.
The code below the `MessageBox` will not execute until after 10 OK buttons are pressed.
But the timer continues to fire even if the execution is blocked.

Try this code

```
int counter = 0;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    counter++; 
    if (counter == 10){
       timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Hello"); 
}
```

(just moved the MessageBox)

Comment: not the mbx itself. Event if there's no user-interface code, it doesn't stop

Comment: If I take your code above and replace the MessageBox with `Console.WriteLine` it stops after 10 iterations. You must have something else wrong in your code. You need to show more code.

Answer (score 1):

What about timer1.Stop()?  I am not too familiar with this class, but looked it up quickly: [Timer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)

Comment: `Stop` does nothing but `this.Enabled = false;`.

Comment: virtual -1. `Calling the Start method is the same as setting Enabled to true. Likewise, calling the Stop method is the same as setting Enabled to false.`

Comment: "Calling the Start method is the same as setting Enabled to true. Likewise, calling the Stop method is the same as setting Enabled to false." from your link

Comment: Gee, it wasn't necessary to have three comments on this answer all saying the same thing...

Comment: Sorry - you guys are right.  My main goal was to link the developer to the tool necessary to answer the question, but you are right - I should have done due diligence.

Answer (score 1):

It is also working for me. I placed the timer in the form, on the button click, I am calling timer1.start() and I put the following code in the tick event and its working.

```
int i = 0;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i++;
    this.Text = i.ToString();
    if (i == 10)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

You need to call Stop.

```
int i = 0;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i++;
    if (i == 10)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: "calling the Stop method is the same as setting Enabled to false."

Comment: You have removed the magic `MessageBox`, that is the tricky (but not obvious) part.

Comment: @Albin Sunnanbo: It really irritating with small interval.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
int counter = 0;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    MessageBox.Show("Hello"); 
    counter++; 
    if (counter == 10){
       timer1.Stop();
       timer1.Dispose();
       timer1 = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: We have made the reference null but what about the object itself? it stills alive

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the `MessageBox` is the culprit here. Maybe if you use a short execution interval for the timer handler then this could potentially cause your code to function undesirably, if executions are overlapping.

The problem would be, in this case, that the handler executes and displays the `MessageBox` which in turn halts execution of the current scope until the the prompt is acknowledged by the user, meanwhile the handler has started again, showing another prompt, and another, and so on. At this point, we have multiple `MessageBox`es waiting for input, yet `counter` hasn't even been incremented once. When we click 'OK' on the prompt, `counter` increments as desired, but at this point has a value of `1`, rather than a value representing the number of prompts shown. This means yet another prompt will be displayed if more time elapses, until the user clicks 'OK' on at least `10` prompts.

You could try inhibiting execution if the process is already under way in order to prevent concurrent runs:

```
private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim Locker = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

int counter = 0;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (Locker.TryEnterWriteLock(0))
    {
        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
            Counter++;
            if (Counter == 10)
            {
                Timer.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        catch { }
        finally
        {
            Locker.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```